# Asp.net MVC Code First Connection Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am expreimenting with asp.net mvc code first technique and want to make a new database with my code but i am not able to get access to my server management studio it gives the error

```
Cannot open database "Webstore.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'sa'.
```

Here is my webconfig connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DBCS" connectionString="Server=HAIDER-PC; 
Database=Webstore.mdf;User ID=sa; Password=123456;"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

here is my code for DBCS class

```
namespace vidly.Models
{
 public class DBCS: DbContext
 {
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
 }
}
```

NOTE: My sa password is correct, my SQL server is on same machine, i can create the database by modifying connection in server explorer and then click "Yes" on the dialog box which says database does not exist do you want to create new?

Comment: Did you set your authentication mode to mixed and restarted the server?

Comment: Yes Phiter it is already on mixed mode and i restarted the server but still the problem is same.